# How can I retrieve the information I want using MySQL `joins` or Laravel `relationships`?

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5.1

I am working on a project using the `Laravel` framework. In this project I have three tables:

---

1) Master Part Numbers (master_part_numbers)

Columns: id, part_number

Values: 1, MS26778-042

---

2) Inventory (inventory)

Columns: id, master_part_number, stock_qty

Values: 1, 1, 7

---

3) Inventory Min Maxes (inventory_min_maxes)

Columns: id, master_part_number, min_qty

Values: 1, 1, 10

---

I am trying to find the inventory where the stock level is below the min_qty. I have been attempting this using `joins`, like so:

```
$test = MasterPartNumber::table('master_part_numbers')
                            ->join('inventory', 'master_part_numbers.id', '=', 'inventory.master_part_number_id')
                            ->join('inventory_min_maxes', 'master_part_numbers.id', '=', 'inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number_id')
                            ->select('master_part_numbers.part_number')
                            ->where('inventory.stock_qty', '<=', 'inventory_min_maxes.min_qty')
                            ->get();
```

However I am getting an empty `collection` every time. I have tried removing the `where()` clause and I get all the part numbers in the inventory, so it feels like I'm on the right track, but missing a critical component.

Also, I don't know if there is an easier or more efficient way to do this using Laravel's Eloquent Relationships, but that option is available.

**Note:** I added the space after `table('master_part_numbers')` in my query displayed here on purpose, for readability.

**EDIT 1:**

This sql query returns the expect result:

```
SELECT master_part_numbers.part_number
FROM master_part_numbers
JOIN inventory ON master_part_numbers.id=inventory.master_part_number_id
JOIN inventory_min_maxes ON master_part_numbers.id=inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number_id
WHERE inventory.stock_qty<=inventory_min_maxes.min_qty;
```

**EDIT 2:**

I finally got it working with some help from the Laravel IRC, however it isn't ideal because I am missing out on some of the data I would like to display, normally collected through relationships.

Here is what I am currently using, but I hope to get refactored:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT master_part_numbers.id, master_part_numbers.part_number, master_part_numbers.description, inventory.stock_qty, inventory.base_location_id, inventory_min_maxes.min_qty, inventory_min_maxes.max_qty
FROM master_part_numbers 
JOIN inventory ON master_part_numbers.id = inventory.master_part_number_id
JOIN inventory_min_maxes ON master_part_numbers.id = inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number_id
WHERE inventory.stock_qty <= inventory_min_maxes.min_qty'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way to solve this problem using the `Laravel` `->whereRAW()` statement:

```
$test = $inventory->join('inventory_min_maxes', 'inventory.id', '=', 'inventory.inventory_min_max_id')
                ->whereRaw('inventory.stock_qty <= inventory_min_maxes.min_qty')
                ->whereRaw('inventory.inventory_min_max_id = inventory_min_maxes.id') // required so it tests against the specific record, without it will test against all records.
                ->get();
```

The major advantage for me, other than it looked terribly ugly before, was that I can now use the power of `relationships`.

**Note:** $inventory is an instance of my `Inventory` model, which I type hinted in the `index()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly then 
'masters_part_numbers.id' == 'inventory.id'     and
'inventory.master_part_number' == 'inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number'

```
$test = DB::table('master_part_numbers')
   ->join('inventory', 'master_part_numbers.id', '=', 'inventory.id')
   ->join('inventory_min_maxes', 'inventory.master_part_number', '=', 'inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number')
   ->where('inventory.stock_qty', '<=', 'inventory_min_maxes.min_qty')
   ->whereNotNull('inventory_min_maxes.master_part_number');
   ->select(DB::raw('part_number'))
   ->get();
```

Based on above criteria. This code will work. I tried in laravel 5.4 .
Try and let me know. nd if it work give me a thumbs up

Comment: There isn't a column in the tables `inventory_min_maxes` or `inventory` called `master_part_number`, so I switched those to `master_part_number_id`. Also, I got a strtolower error because of the `DB::raw()`. When I removed that line I got the same result as before, which is an empty collection.

Comment: The error I got was: `ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`